# Loading 140 mb xml by using simplexml_load_file

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, large-file-upload

I am trying to parse XML of size 140mb with `simplexml_load_file()` like this

```
$sxe = simplexml_load_file("file.xml"); 
print_r($sxe);
```

it only return the object

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [version] => 2.12
            [vocab-version] => 2015-09-08-01
        )

)
```

but the same code works on server. I have tried everything, increasing memory limit, uploaded size etc but didn't get any success. And the same code works for some small xml files.

Comment: could you please provide any more information? for example the *code* we  are supposed to debug?

Comment: sure,iam using this $sxe = simplexml_load_file("file.xml");
print_r($sxe);

Comment: **don't** post code in comments. **edit** your original post instead.

Comment: and as i suppose it should return the object with all the attribute from the xml, but it only return version (as i mention above)

Comment: You can combine XMLReader with SimpleXML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24084203/replacing-parsing-function-with-xmlreader-in-specific-php-code/24084918#24084918 This way only a part of the XML will be loaded into memory.

Comment: my xml has a different structure ,it is not suitable for the example listed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24084203/replacing-parsing-function-with-xmlreader-in-specific-php-code/24084918#24084918

Answer (score 0):

```
$simplexml = simplexml_load_file($file_path, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_PARSEHUGE|LIBXML_NSCLEAN);
//OR
$simplexml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_string, LIBXML_PARSEHUGE|LIBXML_NSCLEAN);
```

Can you run this code like this example?

Comment: Please try search in google with LIBXML_PARSEHUGE|LIBXML_NSCLEAN you can see lot of max size file solution,

Comment: $xsl->loadXML(file_get_contents('xml_path'), LIBXML_PARSEHUGE);iam able to parse by this but actually i want the object of simple xml element,can you help me in coverting the dom document object to simple xml